# Ошибка при создании XML файла в Unity3D

Tags: c#, xml, unity3d

Я имею ошибки и из-за нее не создается файл сохранения.

Код системы сохранения:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

using System.IO;
using System.Xml.Serialization;
using System.Xml;

public class Save : MonoBehaviour
{
    public S PlayerInfo;

    public void SaveGame()
    {
        XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer (typeof(S));
        FileStream stream = new FileStream (Application.dataPath + "/StreamingFiles/XML/Saves.xml", FileMode.Create);
        serializer.Serialize (stream, PlayerInfo);
        stream.Close ();
    }
}
```

Код игрока:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class S : MonoBehaviour
{
    public bool Damaged;
    public float Health; 
    public float Armor;
}
```

Ошибка:

```
InvalidOperationException: To be XML serializable, types which inherit from IEnumerable must have an implementation of Add(System.Object) at all levels of their inheritance hierarchy. UnityEngine.Transform does not implement Add(System.Object).
System.Xml.Serialization.TypeData.get_ListItemType ()
System.Xml.Serialization.TypeData.get_ListItemTypeData ()
System.Xml.Serialization.TypeData..ctor (System.Type type, System.String elementName, Boolean isPrimitive, System.Xml.Serialization.TypeData mappedType, System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaPatternFacet facet)
System.Xml.Serialization.TypeData..ctor (System.Type type, System.String elementName, Boolean isPrimitive)
System.Xml.Serialization.TypeTranslator.GetTypeData (System.Type runtimeType, System.String xmlDataType)
System.Xml.Serialization.TypeTranslator.GetTypeData (System.Type type)
System.Xml.Serialization.XmlReflectionImporter.GetReflectionMembers (System.Type type)
System.Xml.Serialization.XmlReflectionImporter.ImportClassMapping (System.Xml.Serialization.TypeData typeData, System.Xml.Serialization.XmlRootAttribute root, System.String defaultNamespace)
System.Xml.Serialization.XmlReflectionImporter.ImportTypeMapping (System.Xml.Serialization.TypeData typeData, System.Xml.Serialization.XmlRootAttribute root, System.String defaultNamespace)
Rethrow as InvalidOperationException: There was an error reflecting type 'S'.
System.Xml.Serialization.XmlReflectionImporter.ImportTypeMapping (System.Xml.Serialization.TypeData typeData, System.Xml.Serialization.XmlRootAttribute root, System.String defaultNamespace)
System.Xml.Serialization.XmlReflectionImporter.ImportTypeMapping (System.Type type, System.Xml.Serialization.XmlRootAttribute root, System.String defaultNamespace)
System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer..ctor (System.Type type, System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeOverrides overrides, System.Type[] extraTypes, System.Xml.Serialization.XmlRootAttribute root, System.String defaultNamespace)
System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer..ctor (System.Type type)
Save.SaveGame () (at Assets/Save.cs:34)
UnityEngine.Events.InvokableCall.Invoke (System.Object[] args) (at C:/buildslave/unity/build/Runtime/Export/UnityEvent.cs:154)
UnityEngine.Events.InvokableCallList.Invoke (System.Object[] parameters) (at C:/buildslave/unity/build/Runtime/Export/UnityEvent.cs:637)
UnityEngine.Events.UnityEventBase.Invoke (System.Object[] parameters) (at C:/buildslave/unity/build/Runtime/Export/UnityEvent.cs:773)
UnityEngine.Events.UnityEvent.Invoke () (at C:/buildslave/unity/build/Runtime/Export/UnityEvent_0.cs:52)
UnityEngine.UI.Button.Press () (at C:/buildslave/unity/build/Extensions/guisystem/UnityEngine.UI/UI/Core/Button.cs:35)
UnityEngine.UI.Button.OnPointerClick (UnityEngine.EventSystems.PointerEventData eventData) (at C:/buildslave/unity/build/Extensions/guisystem/UnityEngine.UI/UI/Core/Button.cs:44)
UnityEngine.EventSystems.ExecuteEvents.Execute (IPointerClickHandler handler, UnityEngine.EventSystems.BaseEventData eventData) (at C:/buildslave/unity/build/Extensions/guisystem/UnityEngine.UI/EventSystem/ExecuteEvents.cs:50)
UnityEngine.EventSystems.ExecuteEvents.Execute[IPointerClickHandler] (UnityEngine.GameObject target, UnityEngine.EventSystems.BaseEventData eventData, UnityEngine.EventSystems.EventFunction`1 functor) (at C:/buildslave/unity/build/Extensions/guisystem/UnityEngine.UI/EventSystem/ExecuteEvents.cs:261)
UnityEngine.EventSystems.EventSystem:Update()
```

Answer (score 1):

Ты пытаешься провести операцию над объектом, который содержит `UnityEngine.Transform`,  в котором не имплементирован (не реализован) метод `Add(System.Object)`. Это скорее всего идет из-за наследования от `Monobehaviour`.

Можно (и даже нужно) сделать класс `S` не унаследованный от `Monobehaviour` с данной структурой, а отдельно, например в игроке как раз унаследоваться от моно и сделать поле с типом `S`

```
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Serialization;

public class PlayerInfo {
    [XmlAttribute("damaged")]
    public bool Damaged;
    [XmlAttribute("health")]
    public float Health; 
    [XmlAttribute("armor")]
    public float Armor;
}


public class Player : MonoBehaviour {
    public PlayerInfo PlayerInfoField = new PlayerInfo();        
    ...
    Start() {
     ...
    }
}
```

В таком случае не должно быть проблем.

P.S. я класс `S` заменил классом `PlayerInfo`, что логично и информативнее.

Сохранение

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

using System.IO;
using System.Xml.Serialization;
using System.Xml;

public class Save : MonoBehaviour {
    public Player player;

    public void SaveGame()
    {
        XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer (typeof(PlayerInfo));
        FileStream stream = new FileStream (Application.dataPath + "/StreamingFiles/XML/Saves.xml", FileMode.Create);
        serializer.Serialize(stream, player.PlayerInfoField);
        stream.Close ();
    }
}
```

Comment: То есть это все нужно указать в игроке?

Comment: А в коде сохранения вместо: XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer (typeof(S));

Comment: Нужно: XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer (typeof(PlayerInfoField)); ?

Comment: @Helios `То есть это все нужно указать в игроке` - но ведь это вполне логично, разве нет? связанное с игроком поле иметь у него внутри. Можно и не у игрока хранить, но в любом случае класс унаследованный от `monobehaviour` нельзя сериализовать из-за transform .... разве что только поля..... но у тебя логика идет на сохранение всего класса......... ...... нужно будет писать `XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer (typeof(PlayerInfo));` ........ просто класс `S` не самое лучшее имя для класса....но если хочешь можешь оставить его...

Comment: Теперь пишет: DirectoryNotFoundException

Comment: А помечать переменные класса в коде сохранения лучше так?

Comment: public class Save : MonoBehaviour
{
 public PlayerInfo PI;
 public void SaveGame()
 {
  XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer (typeof(PlayerInfo));
  FileStream stream = new FileStream (Application.dataPath + "/Assets/StreamingFiles/XML/Info.xml", FileMode.Create);
  serializer.Serialize (stream, PI);
  stream.Close ();
 }
}

Comment: @Helios `DirectoryNotFoundException` - как видно из названия означает, что директория куда сохраняешь - не найдена... неправильный путь крч......... да сохранять так. только с путями разберись......`Application.dataPath` вроде уже сохраняет в директорию юнити в папку `Assets` https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Application-dataPath.html, так что скорее всего ты зря еще раз дополнительно это пишешь

Comment: @Helios кажется с сохранением чуть по другому.... нужно же брать `PlayerInfo` из игрока........ написал в конце ответа как это должно в теории выглядеть

Answer (score 1):

Мы в своих проектах давненько используем [небольшой пакет](http://unity3d.ru/distribution/viewtopic.php?f=13&t=1039&start=60&st=0&sk=t&sd=a) для сохранения данных в xml и binary. Получается достаточно быстро и удобно.
Для начала делаем сериализуемый объект с настройками которые планируем сохранять, что-то вроде такого:

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

[Serializable]
public class NetworkSetup
{

public bool isServer = false;
public int port = 9593;
public string host = "127.0.0.1";
public int numScreen = 0;

public NetworkSetup()
{
    isServer = false;
    port = 9593;
    host = "127.0.0.1";
    numScreen = 0;
}
}
```

Чтобы использовать эти настройки достаточно объявить переменную, и сделать при `Awake` или `Start` загрузку параметров, ну и если требуется то при закрытие объекта на `OnDestroy` делаем сохранение параметров, выглядит это так:

```
public class NetworkLinker : NetworkManager
{
public string FileSetup = "";
NetworkSetup setup;
private void Awake()
{
    try
    {
        setup = XMLSaver<NetworkSetup>.Load(FileSetup);
    }
    catch (Exception exception)
    {
        Debug.LogWarning("Ошибка при загрузке файла с настройками: " + exception.Message, this);
        setup = new NetworkSetup();
    }

}

void OnDestroy()
{
    XMLSaver<NetworkSetup>.Save(setup, FileSetup); 
// здесь третьим параметром можно указать дополнительные типы которые 
// должны быть сериализованы добавив их список
// XMLSaver<NetworkSetup>.Save(setup, FileSetup, new[] { typeof(PageLink)}); 
// не всегда это надо, но иногда приходится если сериализатор сам их не находит

}
///... остальной код
}
```

ну а дальше везде в коде вы по мере необходимости уже работаете с объектом `setup` напрямую. Все просто и удобно.